# Deal with negative values resulting from my nn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a simple `nn` model that looks like this

```
class TestRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs, n_neurons, n_outputs):
        super(TestRNN, self).__init__()
        ...
        self.basic_rnn = nn.RNN(self.n_inputs, self.n_neurons)
        self.FC = nn.Linear(self.n_neurons, self.n_outputs)


    def forward(self, X):
        ...
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.basic_rnn(X, self.hidden)
        out = self.FC(self.hidden)

        return out.view(-1, self.n_outputs)
```

and I am using `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` for calculating my error.  The operation order goes something like this:

```
# get the inputs
x, y = data

# forward + backward + optimize
outputs = model(x)
loss = criterion(outputs, y)
```

Where my training data `x` is normalized and looks like this:

```
tensor([[[7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [2.6164e-02, 2.6164e-02, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 1.3108e-05],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [9.5062e-01, 3.1036e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [0.0000e+00, 1.3717e-05, 3.2659e-07,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 3.2659e-07]],

        [[5.1934e-01, 5.4041e-01, 6.8083e-06,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 6.8083e-06],
         [5.2340e-01, 6.0007e-01, 2.7062e-06,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 2.7062e-06],
         [8.1923e-01, 5.7346e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]],

        [[7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0714e-01, 7.0708e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 7.0407e-06],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]],

        ...,

        [[7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.1852e-01, 2.3411e-02, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0775e-01, 7.0646e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 3.9888e-06],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]],

        [[5.9611e-01, 5.8796e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0710e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.7538e-01, 2.4842e-01, 1.7787e-06,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 1.7787e-06],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00]],

        [[5.2433e-01, 5.2433e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [1.3155e-01, 1.3155e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 8.6691e-02,
          9.7871e-01, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.4412e-01, 6.6311e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
         [7.0711e-01, 7.0711e-01, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00, 9.6093e-07]]])
```

While a typical `output` and `y` passed to the criterion function look like this:

```
tensor([[-0.0513],
        [-0.0445],
        [-0.0514],
        [-0.0579],
        [-0.0539],
        [-0.0323],
        [-0.0521],
        [-0.0294],
        [-0.0372],
        [-0.0518],
        [-0.0516],
        [-0.0501],
        [-0.0312],
        [-0.0496],
        [-0.0436],
        [-0.0514],
        [-0.0518],
        [-0.0465],
        [-0.0530],
        [-0.0471],
        [-0.0344],
        [-0.0502],
        [-0.0536],
        [-0.0594],
        [-0.0356],
        [-0.0371],
        [-0.0513],
        [-0.0528],
        [-0.0621],
        [-0.0404],
        [-0.0403],
        [-0.0562],
        [-0.0510],
        [-0.0580],
        [-0.0516],
        [-0.0556],
        [-0.0063],
        [-0.0459],
        [-0.0494],
        [-0.0460],
        [-0.0631],
        [-0.0525],
        [-0.0454],
        [-0.0509],
        [-0.0522],
        [-0.0426],
        [-0.0527],
        [-0.0423],
        [-0.0572],
        [-0.0308],
        [-0.0452],
        [-0.0555],
        [-0.0479],
        [-0.0513],
        [-0.0514],
        [-0.0498],
        [-0.0514],
        [-0.0471],
        [-0.0505],
        [-0.0467],
        [-0.0485],
        [-0.0520],
        [-0.0517],
        [-0.0442]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

When the criterion is being applied I get the following error (running with CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1):

```
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THCUNN/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:105: void cunn_ClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput_kernel(Dtype *, Dtype *, Dtype *, long *, Dtype *, int, int, int, int, long) [with Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [0,0,0], thread: [7,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THCUNN/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:105: void cunn_ClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput_kernel(Dtype *, Dtype *, Dtype *, long *, Dtype *, int, int, int, int, long) [with Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [0,0,0], thread: [20,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu line=111 error=59 : device-side assert triggered
```

The fact that my model outputs negative values is causing the error message above, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You have two options:

1. Make the second dimension of `outputs` be of size 2 instead of 1.
2. Use `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` instead of `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`

---

I think that the problem is not the negative numbers. It is the shape of `outputs`.

Looking at your array `y`, I see that you have 2 different classes (maybe even more, but let's suppose that it's 2). This means that the last dimension of `outputs` should be 2. The reason is that `outputs` needs to give a "score" to each one of the 2 different classes (see [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)). The score can be negative, zero or positive. But the shape of your `outputs` is `[64,1]`, and not `[64,2]` as required.

One of the steps of the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` object will be to convert these scores to a probability distribution over the two classes. This is done using a softmax operation. However, When doing binary classification (that is, classification with only 2 classes, as in our current case), there is another option: Give a score for only one class, convert it to a probability for that class using a sigmoid function, and then perform "1-p" on this to get the probability for the other class. This option means that `outputs` needs to give a score for only one of the two classes, as in you current case. To chose this options, you will need to change `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` with `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`. You can then pass to it `outputs` and `y` as you are currently doing (note however that the shape of `outputs` needs to be precisely the shape of `y`, so in your example you will need to pass `outputs[:,0]` instead of `outputs`. Also you will need to convert `y` to a float: `y.float()`. Thus the call is `criterion(outputs[:,0], y.float())`)

Comment: I need to choose between two classes, True (1) and Zero (0), what you are saying makes perfect sense though.